# A function calling another function

Tags: sml, smlnj

Let's say i have two SML functions Ping and Pong.My code is this:

```
val arr=Array.array(10,0)

fun Ping (arr,_,[],_)=true
   |Ping (arr,0,(x::xs),ping_list)=Ping(arr,1,xs,Pong(arr,ping_list,10)) //<-Problem is here
   | Ping (arr,K,(x :: xs),ping_list) =
        (if Array.sub(arr,x)=0
        then
         Array.update(arr, x, Array.sub(arr,x)+1)
        else
          Array.update(arr, x, Array.sub(arr,x)+1);
        if Array.sub(arr,x)-1<1 then Ping (arr,(K-1),xs,(x::ping_list)) else Ping (arr,K,xs,(x::ping_list)))



fun Pong arr [] _ =[]
   |Pong arr (x::xs) min=
   (if Array.sub(arr,x)>=1 
      then  Array.update(arr,x,Array.sub(arr,x)-1)
      else();
   if Array.sub(arr,x)+1>1 
         then if (length xs)<min then Pong arr xs (length xs)
          else Pong arr xs min
   else xs)
```

If i call Ping with let's say an array,3:int,[1,2,3]:list,[] it gives me the disired output.In like manner,if i call Pong with an array,list,integer it gives me the output i want.In the ping funcrion if K=0 i want to call the pong function(which modifies an array) and call recursively Ping function but in parameter ping_list have the result of Pong(which is a list) However running thisgives me this error:

```
stdIn:27.40-27.73 Error: operator and operand do not agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: int array
  operand:         'Z * 'Y * [int ty]
  in expression:
    Pong (arr,ping_list,10)
```

I have also tried putting Ping and Pong inside a local and calling Ping from the in but it does not seem to work.How could this be solved?

Comment: What version of SML are you using? I tried running your code but it had multiple problems preventing me from running it, the mutual recursion between `Ping` and `Pong` and missing parentheses/semicolons being the biggest. But after fixing the syntax, the program seems to work for me.

Comment: I am running  v110.85, could you please post the code that works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Control.Print.printDepth := 20;

val arr = Array.array(10,0)

fun Ping (arr, _, [], _) = true
   |Ping (arr, 0, (x::xs), ping_list) = Ping(arr, 1, xs, Pong(arr, ping_list, 10))
   |Ping (arr, K, (x :: xs), ping_list) =
        (if Array.sub(arr, x) = 0
        then Array.update(arr, x, Array.sub(arr, x)+1)
        else Array.update(arr, x, Array.sub(arr, x)+1);
        if Array.sub(arr, x)-1 < 1
        then Ping(arr, (K-1), xs, (x::ping_list))
        else Ping(arr, K, xs, (x::ping_list)))
and Pong(arr, [], _) = []
   |Pong(arr, (x::xs), min) =
    (if Array.sub(arr, x) >= 1 
      then (Array.update(arr, x, Array.sub(arr, x)-1); [])
      else [];
    if Array.sub(arr,x) + 1 > 1 
        then if (length xs) < min then Pong(arr, xs, (length xs)) else Pong(arr, xs, min)
   else xs);

val result = Ping(arr, 3, [0, 2, 4], []);
val it = arr;
```

Output:

```
val arr = [|0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0|] : int array
val Ping = fn : int array * int * int list * int list -> bool
val Pong = fn : int array * int list * int -> int list
val result = true : bool
val it = [|1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0|] : int array
```

Problems that I fixed before I could run it:

- Pong return types were not consistent(mixing `()` and `int list`)
- Ping and Pong were not defined mutually
- Mixed curried and non-curried definition/calls of Pong